# BigQuery Partition By List

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, database-partitioning

Does BigQuery support partition by list or by range? The online document seems to say that it only supports partition by date. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, BigQuery support partitioning only by date!
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

See also request for supporting non-date partitioning
Vote on it if you need this feature
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817